# Масштабирование блока под размер фона

Tags: css3

```css
.no-image {
    background: url('/assets/images/no-image.jpg') no-repeat center center #FFF;
    background-size: contain;
}
.categories {
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories no-image" style="
     background: url('http://pir.uborka25.ru/assets/img/sets/035nb-zhivi-yarko.jpg') no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     margin: 1%;
     ">
<div class="categories-dark">
<span class="hint">C кремом</span>
<div class="link-category">
 <a href="kapkeyki  /s-kremom/" title="Классические капкейки с кремом">Выбрать </a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Надо чтоб высота блока зависела от высоты картинки при заданной ширине. На чистом css, js реализация уже есть(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут придётся реальную картинку  вставлять, css -ом такое не сделать

Comment: Отмечу как правильный даже, у самого такие же грустные мысли)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, но может быть подойдет одно из двух.

```css
.no-image-1 {
  background: url('http://pir.uborka25.ru/assets/img/sets/035nb-zhivi-yarko.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.categories {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
}

.no-image-2 {
  background: url('http://pir.uborka25.ru/assets/img/sets/035nb-zhivi-yarko.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories no-image-1">
  <div class="categories-dark">
    <span class="hint">C кремом</span>
    <div class="link-category">
      <a href="kapkeyki  /s-kremom/" title="Классические капкейки с кремом">Выбрать </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="categories no-image-2">
  <div class="categories-dark">
    <span class="hint">C кремом</span>
    <div class="link-category">
      <a href="kapkeyki  /s-kremom/" title="Классические капкейки с кремом">Выбрать </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению не то( Смотрите: я задаю ширину в процентах, и мне надо чтоб высота блока была равна ПОЛНОЙ высоте картинки, с шириной в данное к-во процентов

Comment: Мне кажется вам подходит пример слева `no-image-1`, в нем задана минимальная высота `min-height: 400px` равная высоте картинки.